# Spring OAuth2 not redirecting to Access Token

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have been trying to configure Spring OAuth2. Have been partially successful.

In order to test that I have been using SOAPui and setting the redirect-uri as "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob".

The issue with my system is that I can go to get an authorization code but then it will not redirect to the authorization server to get an access code. I have been looking at logs and I see that the URL is not defined there, it is not doing /app/oauth/token?code=OB05Cb instead it just do ?code=OB05Cb on the url

DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView: unnamed; URL [urn:?code=OB05Cb]]

Then it shows a page not found on my SoapUI and stops the workflow.

I believe that I am missing some interceptor that is not doing it. I have no idea why it is not moving forward. Can anyone give me some hints on it? Thanks!

I am using Spring OAuth2 version 2.0.3.RELEASE
4.0.5.RELEASE
3.2.5.RELEASE

Here's my configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:oauth2="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd">

<beans:bean id="tokenStore"
    class="com.nando.api.service.CassandraTokenStore" />

<beans:bean id="codes"
        class="com.nando.api.service.CassandraAuthorizationCodeService" />

<beans:bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <beans:property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Added this -->
<beans:bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationManager">
        <beans:property name="resourceId" value="nando"/>
        <beans:property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="tokenExtractor" 
           class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.BearerTokenExtractor"/>

   <beans:bean id="userService" class="com.nando.api.service.DefaultUserService" />
    <beans:bean id="webServiceClientService"
        class="com.nando.api.service.DefaultWebServiceClientService" />
    <beans:bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="webServiceClientService" />
        <!-- might need or not to set the passwordEncoder -->
        <!-- <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" /> -->
    </beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="oauthRequestFactory"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
    <!-- Added this -->
    <beans:property name="checkUserScopes" value="true" />
    <!-- TODO arguments here -->
    <beans:constructor-arg name="clientDetailsService"
        ref="webServiceClientService" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userApprovalHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
        <!-- TODO here -->
        <beans:property name="requestFactory" ref="oauthRequestFactory" />
        <beans:property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <beans:property name="clientDetailsService" ref="webServiceClientService" />
    </beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="resolver" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.DefaultRedirectResolver" />

<beans:bean id="requestValidator" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestValidator" />

 <oauth2:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="webServiceClientService" 
 token-services-ref="tokenServices" user-approval-page="/oauth/userapproval" 
 error-page="/oauth/error" authorization-endpoint-url="/oauth/authorize" token-endpoint-url="/oauth/token" user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
 <oauth2:authorization-code
            authorization-code-services-ref="codes" />
        <oauth2:refresh-token/>
        <oauth2:password/>
 </oauth2:authorization-server>

<!-- Spring Security Authentication Managers -->

<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />

<sec:authentication-manager alias="userAuthenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
            <sec:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
        </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>

<sec:authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService"/>
</sec:authentication-manager>

<oauth2:resource-server id="oauth2ProviderFilter" 
            authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" token-extractor-ref="tokenExtractor" token-services-ref="tokenServices"/>

<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

<beans:bean id="webSecurityExpressionHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.expression.OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler" />

<beans:bean id="methodSecurityExpressionHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.expression.OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler" />

<beans:bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<beans:bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint" />


<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"
        order="0" proxy-target-class="true">
        <sec:expression-handler ref="methodSecurityExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>


<sec:http security="none" pattern="/resource/**" />
<sec:http security="none" pattern="/favicon.ico" />

<beans:bean id="corsFilter" class="com.nando.api.filters.SpringCrossOriginResourceSharingFilter"/>

<!-- Maybe change the create-session here -->
<sec:http use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless"
    authentication-manager-ref="userAuthenticationManager"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" pattern="/oauth/token">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="hasAuthority('OAUTH_CLIENT')" />
    <sec:http-basic />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    <sec:expression-handler ref="webSecurityExpressionHandler" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="corsFilter" after="LAST"/>
</sec:http>

<!-- Here is where the Services endpoints are secured -->
<sec:http use-expressions="true" create-session="never"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" pattern="/services/**">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/services/**"
        access="hasAuthority('USE_WEB_SERVICES')" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="oauth2ProviderFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    <sec:expression-handler ref="webSecurityExpressionHandler" />
</sec:http>

<!-- General security -->
<sec:http use-expressions="true">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/session/list"
        access="hasAuthority('VIEW_USER_SESSIONS')" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/**"
        access="hasAuthority('USE_WEB_SERVICES')" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="permitAll()" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll()" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/scope/**" access="permitAll()" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/scope" access="permitAll()" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll()" />
    <sec:form-login default-target-url="/" login-page="/login"
        login-processing-url="/login/submit" authentication-failure-url="/login?loginFailed"
        username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />
    <sec:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login?loggedOut"
        delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" />
    <sec:session-management invalid-session-url="/login"
        session-fixation-protection="changeSessionId">
        <sec:concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"
            max-sessions="1" session-registry-ref="sessionRegistry" />
    </sec:session-management>
    <sec:csrf />
    <sec:expression-handler ref="webSecurityExpressionHandler" />
</sec:http>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: I think you have to exchange code for accessToken manually at server side.

Comment: That does not seem to be logical. The fact that the URL is [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView: unnamed; URL [urn:?code=OB05Cb]] instead of the full thing seems to me that there is something wrong.

Comment: No that's all working fine. If you read the spec a bit you will see the flow defined quite explicitly. You need to exchange the auth code for an access token.

Comment: Well, I cannot even go to /oauth/token.

I've checked the security filter which I have added as:

DelegatingFilterProxy delegatingFilterProxy = new org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain");
  FilterRegistration.Dynamic securityFilterDynamic = container.addFilter("securityFilter",delegatingFilterProxy);
  securityFilterDynamic.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class),true,"/*");

Comment: Just try to do this : http://<Server-url>/oauth/token , add the header  Authorization: Basic <Base64 encode of clientId:secret> and send request param grant_type=authorization_code&code=OB05Cb&redirect_uri=<RedirectURL>

Comment: Thanks. I did your suggestion and got error on authentication code.

Here's my request:

curl -v -X POST -d "grant_type=authorization_code&code=umlslv&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" -H "Authorization: Basic Te+/vS0KWO+/ve+/vd2a77+9TO+/vWfvv73vv70o77+977+977+9Qu+/vX3vv73duiHvv71Q1ZptL3wkHO+/ve+/ve+/vWJy56qd77+977+9Aynvv70=" 'http://localhost:8080/nandoAPI/oauth/token'

Here's the log: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

Comment: The clue to this problem is here:   

DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView: unnamed; URL [urn:?code=OB05Cb]]

Instead of doing what is anticipated, which is to return a HTML page with "Success code=OB05Cb" as the title (see https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#choosingredirecturi), Spring is trying to redirect.

In the 2.0.9.RELEASE version of spring-security-oauth2, I believe the problem is in o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.getAuthorizationCodeResponse

Comment: Seems support for this feature was added in 13 Feb 2015, but was never merged.   https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/pull/402